# QuickBooks InventoryAdjustMod

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, quickbooks

In the QuickBooks QBFC SDK, I need to add a line to an inventory adjustment. But for some reason it is telling me that a serial / lot reference is required.

Here is the QBFC reference for an Adjustment Line. It says that the ORTypeAdjustmentMod is a required field, but I don't use serial numbers or lot numbers. The "Y" to the right indicates required fields.

[image]

Here is the XML version of the same request. In this one the ORTypeAdjustmentMod is optional.

I am not quite sure what the <-BEGIN OR-> comments mean but that may tie to the ORTypeAdjustmentMod.

[image]

Has anyone run into something similar to this with the QuickBooks SDK?

*EDIT*

Here is the code calling that is talking to quickbooks. 
There's a global session manager for the whole class and then messages are sent in the SendMessage function. The error from quickbooks when the Lot/Serial numbers are not included is "InventoryAdjustmentLineModList:
element(0) - ORTypeAdjustmentMod: required field is missing
End of InventoryAdjustmentLineModList
End of InventoryAdjustmentMod"

Another issue that i have noticed, which might be to do with the serial/ lot number thing is that when you go to add a new line to an existing inventory adjustment by setting the TxnLineID to "-1", it erases every existing line on the transaction and the adds the new line.  It gives an "OK" status message when this happens.

```
Function AdjustInventory(itemid As String, adjustment As Single, account As String, _class As String, jobnumber As String, reference As String) As String
    Dim requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest
'Checks if previous inventory adjust exists and returns JArray of each line 
'of the transaction. No issue here.
    Dim lines As JArray = GetPreviousQuery(reference)

    requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0)
    requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue
    Dim responseMsgSet As IMsgSetResponse
    Dim exists As Boolean = lines(0)("exists")

'if a previoius adjustment doesnt exist, make a new one.
    If Not exists Then
        Dim InventoryAdjustmentAddRq As IInventoryAdjustmentAdd
        InventoryAdjustmentAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendInventoryAdjustmentAddRq()
        InventoryAdjustmentAddRq.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue(account)
        InventoryAdjustmentAddRq.ClassRef.FullName.SetValue(_class)
        InventoryAdjustmentAddRq.RefNumber.SetValue(reference)
        If jobnumber IsNot Nothing Then
            InventoryAdjustmentAddRq.CustomerRef.FullName.SetValue(jobnumber)
        End If
        Dim InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd91 As IInventoryAdjustmentLineAdd
            InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd91 = InventoryAdjustmentAddRq.InventoryAdjustmentLineAddList.Append()
            InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd91.ItemRef.ListID.SetValue(itemid)
            InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd91.ORTypeAdjustment.QuantityAdjustment.ORQuantityAdjustment.QuantityDifference.SetValue(adjustment)

            responseMsgSet = Me.SendMessage(requestMsgSet)
        Else
            Dim InventoryAdjustmentModRq As IInventoryAdjustmentMod
        InventoryAdjustmentModRq = requestMsgSet.AppendInventoryAdjustmentModRq()
        'InventoryAdjustmentModRq.RefNumber.SetValue(reference)
        InventoryAdjustmentModRq.TxnID.SetValue(lines(0)("transactionid"))
        InventoryAdjustmentModRq.EditSequence.SetValue(lines(0)("editsequence"))

        Dim isitemnew As Boolean = True

'loops through all items in adjustment to see if the current item matches.
        For Each line As JObject In lines
            If line("listid") = itemid Then
                Dim prevquan As Single
                prevquan = line("quantitydifference")
                Dim newval As Single = prevquan + adjustment

                Dim InventoryAdjustmentLineMod116 As IInventoryAdjustmentLineMod
                InventoryAdjustmentLineMod116 = InventoryAdjustmentModRq.InventoryAdjustmentLineModList.Append()
                InventoryAdjustmentLineMod116.ItemRef.ListID.SetValue(itemid)

                InventoryAdjustmentLineMod116.QuantityDifference.SetValue(newval)
                InventoryAdjustmentLineMod116.TxnLineID.SetValue(lines(0)("linetxnid"))
                InventoryAdjustmentLineMod116.ORTypeAdjustmentMod.LotAdjustment.CountAdjustment.SetValue(newval)
                isitemnew = False
            End If

        Next

'If item is new, append it to the inventory adjustment.
        If isitemnew Then
            Dim invadjustlineadd As IInventoryAdjustmentLineMod
            invadjustlineadd = InventoryAdjustmentModRq.InventoryAdjustmentLineModList.Append()
'Heres where the erasing issue arises'
'the transaction doesnt get replaced when the TxnLineID is actually matches 
'an existing TxnLineID, it only happens when trying to add a new one.
            invadjustlineadd.TxnLineID.SetValue("-1")
            invadjustlineadd.ItemRef.ListID.SetValue(itemid)

            invadjustlineadd.QuantityDifference.SetValue(adjustment)

            invadjustlineadd.ORTypeAdjustmentMod.LotAdjustment.CountAdjustment.SetValue(adjustment)
            Debug.WriteLine(invadjustlineadd.TxnLineID.GetValue.ToString)
        End If
        responseMsgSet = Me.SendMessage(requestMsgSet)
    End If








    Dim res As Object = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0)
    Dim code As String = res.StatusCode
    Dim mes As String = res.StatusMessage
    Dim sev As String = res.StatusSeverity
    Dim jres As Object
    jres = New With {Key .status = sev, Key .code = code, Key .detail = mes}
    Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jres)
    Return output



End Function

Function SendMessage(requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest) As IMsgSetResponse

    Dim responseMsgSet As IMsgSetResponse

    'Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks

    responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet)

    'End the session and close the connection to QuickBooks

    Return responseMsgSet
End Function
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What does the XML request you're sending look like? Without this information, we can't help you.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. My question is with the SDK, not necessarily my code. The XML SDK says that they're optional, but the .NET SDK says that they're required.

Comment: What's the actual error message you're getting? What does your code look like?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I updated my question to include all of that. If you don't mind looking it over. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the QuickBooks file doesn't have Serial/Lot numbers turned on? I tested in the sample QuickBooks file and was able to create an inventory quantity adjustment without specifying serial/lot number. My code is C# (and I hard coded values):`QBSessionManager SessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
            SessionManager.OpenConnection2("StackOverflow", "StackOverflow", ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
            SessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);

```
        IMsgSetRequest MsgRequest = SessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
        IInventoryAdjustmentAdd iAdd = MsgRequest.AppendInventoryAdjustmentAddRq();
        iAdd.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Advertising Expense");
        iAdd.RefNumber.SetValue("12345");
        iAdd.TxnDate.SetValue(DateTime.Today);

        IInventoryAdjustmentLineAdd iLine = iAdd.InventoryAdjustmentLineAddList.Append();
        iLine.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue("Indoor Electrical Wire");
        iLine.ORTypeAdjustment.QuantityAdjustment.ORQuantityAdjustment.QuantityDifference.SetValue(10);

        IResponse Response = SessionManager.DoRequests(MsgRequest).ResponseList.GetAt(0); `
```

For the missing lines when modding a transaction, you need to include the lines even if you aren't making changes, per the QBSDK Programmer's Guide. However, you don't need to specify all of the fields for lines that you are not changing. Just include a LineMod with just the TxnLineID for the line and it will be retained. You can get some more details and code samples in the QBSDK Programmer's Guide on page 127-131.

Comment: the issue was not adding the previous lines back to the new transaction mod. I thought of it over lunch and forgot i had posted the question. Thanks!